# python ssl error occruing while i register the form

Tags: python, django, ssl

I am getting the error while i hit the registration button;

SSLError at /registration/register/

[Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Comment: what runserver.. ! local or remote ?

Comment: In my local...Doing python django project, in that am having the register form, while i register, that error is occured..

Comment: Do you have mail function in registration view ?

Comment: yes i m having mail field..EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'


EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'testmail123123'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'testmail123sample@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True     gave these code in settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `EMAIL_BACKEND`

for checking change your email backend to ...

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

And after try this

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: yaa thank u soo much...now cleared the error...one more..while hit the search button..this error shows ..DatabaseError at /search/results/cars/

(1214, "The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes")

Comment: are you writing your own django view or any package ?

Comment: Master gave me,,i try to run the code..dont know there is own django view..sorry..

Comment: ok . see go to search function and see the fetch query from database that causing the issue..

Comment: this is search ...def search_in_category(request, slug):
    # reset the search params, if present
    try:
        del request.session['search']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    return search_results(request, slug)

Comment: This is my search form...<form method="post" action="#">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" class="text" name="keywords" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="{% trans 'Search' %}" />
 </form>

Comment: Not this one .. i need the fetch query from database ... look into your search related views ...

Comment: what db you are using ? And also the version number ?

Comment: @Geetha 5.2 is not supported full text search .. Only thing is you need to upgrade to 5.6 or latest. else upgrade your ENGINE type like `ENGINE=MyISAM;`

Comment: Thats like to change the very table of create query,..but i want to change the table option commonly..is any setting is there to change??

Comment: And also what is difference bettwen console.EmailBackend  and smtp.EmailBackend ini email backend..

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place for chat answering system. If you have further question then ask in SO itself. Or personally i like to help .. come over to private talk n twitter ...

Comment: sorry i am new to this

Comment: how to switch over to private msg